# why is useMatch not working in React router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm learning how to use `useMatch()` from `"react-router-dom"`
I am getting the error below and my web page is blank:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'path')
    at matchPath (index.tsx:1148)
    at index.tsx:481
    at mountMemo (react-dom.development.js:15846)
    at Object.useMemo (react-dom.development.js:16219)
    at useMemo (react.development.js:1532)
    at useMatch (index.tsx:481)
    at About (About.js:7)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049)
```

my code is below

```
import React from "react"
import { useMatch  } from "react-router-dom"
import { Link, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import SinglePage from "./SinglePage"

const About = () => {
  const { url, path } = useMatch()
  console.log("hello usematch!", useMatch())
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}/about-app`}>About App</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}/about-author`}>About Author</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Route path={`${path}/:slug`}>
        <SinglePage />
      </Route>
    </div>
  )
}
export default About
```

And below is the `index.js` file where we get to this about page:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
//component file
import TodoContainer from "./functionBased/components/TodoContainer";
import { Route, Routes, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";


//stylesheet
import "./functionBased/App.css";
import About from "./pages/About";
import NotMatch from "./pages/NotMatch";
//stylesheet
// import "./App.css"
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<TodoContainer />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NotMatch />} />

        </Routes>
      </>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I've tried going through the api [docs](https://react-location.tanstack.com/docs/api) but unclear about why this is not working and how to make the page load. I am trying to return the nearest current route match within the context of where it's called.

I am quite new to react and `router` apis.

Thanks so much

Comment: What was the output for `console.log("hello usematch!", useMatch())`?

Comment: Hi @TarunSharma it's only an error. Nothing came out of the console log

Comment: Could you try `console.log('url: ', url);` and `console.log('path: ', path);` instead, and see what it prints? or is the error happening in the first call to `useMatch()` itself?

Comment: I tried to console log ```console.log('url: ', url); ``` and ```console.log('path: ', path)``` but did not see anything (I'm assuming it's happening with the way userMatch() is being use

Comment: Could you post the code for where you defined your routes?

Comment: Yeah -- thanks for suggesting that. I did it

Comment: The docs link is not correct. It points to another library, not `react-router-dom`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `react-router-dom` v6 the `useMatch` hook takes a ***required*** `pattern` value that is either a string representing a path ***or*** a `PathPattern` object.

[useMatch](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-match)

```
declare function useMatch<ParamKey extends string = string>(
  pattern: PathPattern | string
): PathMatch<ParamKey> | null;
```

PathPattern

```
interface PathPattern {
  path: string;
  caseSensitive?: boolean;
  end?: boolean;
}
```

From what I can tell it appears you are attempting to build "nested" routing using the same pattern as was used in v5. This doesn't work the same in v6 though as v6 can utilize relative linking/routing by not specifying an absolute path starting with a leading `"/"`.

See [Relative Routes and Links](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5#relative-routes-and-links) from the v5 migration guide.

Applying relative linking/routing:

```
const About = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="about-app">About App</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="about-author">About Author</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Route path=":slug">
        <SinglePage />
      </Route>
    </div>
  )
}
```

`react-router-dom` v6 also now always uses exact path matching, so to ensure any nested `Route` components can be matched and rendered you should update the lower paths to allow sub-route matching. If `"/about"` is rendering sub-routes then append a wildcard matcher.

App

```
<Router>
  <Routes>
    <Route exact path="/" element={<TodoContainer />} />
    <Route path="/about/*" element={<About />} />
    <Route path="*" element={<NotMatch />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

Answer (score -4):

It appears that you're using the `Router` from `react-router-dom`, and not the one from the `react-location` library, which is the one which provides the `useMatch()` hook that you need.

You need to use the `Router` from `react-location`, and then link your `<Router>` with the `react-location` library by passing an instance of `ReactLocation` via the `location` prop. I'm basing this off of the docs you linked to in your question.

Your `index.js` should probably look something like

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
//component file
import TodoContainer from "./functionBased/components/TodoContainer";
import { ReactLocation, Router } from 'react-location';

//stylesheet
import "./functionBased/App.css";
import About from "./pages/About";
import NotMatch from "./pages/NotMatch";
//stylesheet
// import "./App.css"

const reactLocation = new ReactLocation();

const routes = [
       {
         path: '/',
         element: <TodoContainer />,
       },
       {
         path: '/about',
         element: <About />,
       },
       {
         element: <NotMatch />,
       },
     ];

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router location={reactLocation}
     routes={routes}>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

[This article](https://dev.to/alexmercedcoder/comparing-react-router-5-6-and-react-location-2d7h) might help clear up the differences on how to use `react-router-dom` vs `react-location`.

Comment: Thanks but `BrowserRouter as Router` is the same, the question is about react-router-dom, not react-location which has a different API.